# Min and max datetime in same table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

```
select WorkDay,
MIN(WorkDay) as dayOn,
MAX(WorkDay) as DayOff
from Records
where YEAR(WorkDay)=2014 and MONTH(WorkDay) =10 and EnNo=10
group by WorkDay
```

Query is showing result like below

```
WorkDays                          DayOn                     Dayoff
2014-10-04 08:13:00.000     2014-10-04 08:13:00.000    2014-10-04 08:13:00.000
2014-10-04 17:19:00.000     2014-10-04 17:19:00.000    2014-10-04 17:19:00.000
```

But i need data like similar below

```
WorkDays                       DayOn                     Dayoff Oct
2014-10-04            2014-10-04 08:13:00.000       2014-10-04 17:19:00.000
```

Some one please sort out this query 
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select WorkDay = cast(floor(cast(WorkDay as float)) as datetime),
MIN(WorkDay) as dayOn,
MAX(WorkDay) as DayOff
from Records
where YEAR(WorkDay)=2014 and MONTH(WorkDay) =10 and EnNo=10
group by  cast(floor(cast(WorkDay as float)) as datetime)
```

Comment: Reputations are less than 15 can't upVote marked as ans,

Answer (score 0):

you can also try the following

```
select CONVERT( date, WorkDay),
MIN(WorkDay) as dayOn,
MAX(WorkDay) as DayOff
from Records
where YEAR(WorkDay)=2014 and MONTH(WorkDay) =10 and EnNo=10
group by CONVERT( date,  WorkDay)
```